How to automate debugging in VSCode similar to GDB `-x gdb_script`?
I'm learning to use Visual Studio Code (VSCode) for my C/C++ project. In the Linux CLI, I usually automate debugging with GDB using the command:
gdb a.out -x gdb_script

This lets me run GDB with a predefined set of commands from a script, which greatly speeds up the debugging process for larger projects.
However, now that my project is growing, manually debugging in VSCode is becoming slow. I'm trying to find a way to automate the debugging process in VSCode, similar to how I use -x gdb_script with GDB.
I have set up the build and debug configurations in launch.json and tasks.json, but I haven’t found a way to include a script for automating the process.
I’ve searched online for solutions and found that some recommend setting breakpoints within the project while debugging. These breakpoints will persist between debugging sessions, making it more convenient to resume debugging later. While this method works, I find it less efficient compared to using an automated script like the -x gdb_script option in GDB.
Any suggestions on how to automate the debugging process in VSCode like using the -x gdb_script with GDB?
Here are my current .vscode configurations:
// launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Current File",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [
                "/home/mwm1c/pmem/intro_1.obj"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        }
    ]
}

// tasks.json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
      {
          "label": "build",
          "type": "cppbuild",
          "command": "gcc",
          "args": [
              "-g",  
              "${file}",  
              "-o", 
              "${fileDirname}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
              "-lpmemobj"
          ],
          "group": {
              "kind": "build",
              "isDefault": true
          },
          "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "new",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
          },
          "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"]
      },
      {
        "label": "run",
        "type": "shell",
        "dependsOn": "build",
        "command": "${fileDirname}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "group": {
          "kind": "test",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
          "echo": true,
          "reveal": "always",
          "focus": true,
          "panel": "new",
        }
      }
  ]
}

